# I'm having problem with moving a player object in Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, game-physics, pygame-surface

I'm having a problem with moving a player object in Pygame. I have created the class of Player and called it on my main file, but whenever I try to move the player object it won't move. I have also called it inside the Game loop but still, it won't move. I don't know what's going on: Here is the code I have done so far:

screen.py

```
import pygame

screen.py
class Screen:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def screen_display(self):
        return pygame.display.set_mode((self.width,self.height))
```

player.py

```
import pygame


class Player:
    playerY_change = 0.5
    def __init__(self, playerX,playerY, playerWidth,playerHeight,screen,):
        self.playerX = playerX
        self.playerY = playerY
        self.playerWidth = playerWidth
        self.playerHeight = playerHeight
        
        self.screen = screen
    def create_player(self):
        return pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, [0, 0, 0], [self.playerX, self.playerY, self.playerWidth, self.playerHeight])
```

enemy.py

```
import pygame


class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, enemyX,enemyY, enemyWidth,enemyHeight,screen):
        self.enemyX = enemyX
        self.enemyY = enemyY
        self.enemyWidth = enemyWidth
        self.enemyHeight = enemyHeight
        self.screen = screen

    def create_enemy(self):
        return pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, [0, 0, 0], [self.enemyX, self.enemyY, self.enemyWidth, self.enemyHeight])
```

Here is my Main file main.py:

```
import pygame,random,math
from screen import Screen
from player import Player
from enemy import Enemy

# Pygame initilaize
pygame.init()

#Game Screen
screenWidth = 800
screenHeight = 500
window = Screen(screenWidth,screenHeight)
screen = window.screen_display()

# Title and Logo
pygame.display.set_caption("ShootBhoot")
icon = pygame.image.load("logo.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# Player
playerX = 10

playerY = 10
playerY_change = 200
playerWidth = 15
playerHeight = 50

player = Player(playerX,playerY,playerWidth,playerHeight,screen)

#Enemy
enemyWidth = 15 
enemyHeight = 50
enemyX = screenWidth - (enemyWidth + 10)
enemyY = 10
enemy = Enemy(enemyX,enemyY,enemyWidth,enemyHeight,screen)

# Ball
ballRadius = 10
ballX = random.randint(0, screenWidth - 10)
ballY = random.randint(0, screenHeight - 10)
ballX_change = 0.01
ballY_change = 0
def ball_create(screen, ballX, ballY, radius):
    return pygame.draw.circle(screen, (10, 10, 10), (ballX, ballY), radius)


def distance(playerX,playerY,ballX,ballY):
    calc = math.sqrt((playerX - ballX)**2 + (playerY - ballY)**2)
    print(calc)

#Game loop
running = True

while running:
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        #Even while I click btn It won't move
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                playerY_change = -0.5

            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                playerY_change = 0.5

    

    # Player Move Object not moving
    playerY = playerY_change


    enemy.create_enemy()
    ball_create(screen, ballX, ballY, ballRadius)
    player.create_player()
    pygame.display.flip()
    


    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: You need to create a move function in Playerclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`playerY` is just used when to create the `player`. You have to change the coordinate attribute of the player:

<s>`playerY = playerY_change`</s>

```py
player.playerY += playerY_change
```

However I recommend to use `pygame.key.get_pressed()` instead of the keyboard events.

The keyboard events (see [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module) occur only once when the state of a key changes. The `KEYDOWN` event occurs once every time a key is pressed. `KEYUP` occurs once every time a key is released. Use the keyboard events for a single action or a step-by-step movement.
[`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) returns a list with the state of each key. If a key is held down, the state for the key is `True`, otherwise `False`. Use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) to evaluate the current state of a button and get continuous movement:

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        player.playerY -= 1
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        player.playerY += 1

    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    enemy.create_enemy()
    ball_create(screen, ballX, ballY, ballRadius)
    player.create_player()
    pygame.display.flip()
```